# C# - Download .exe that launches with parameters

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to host a `.exe file`, that when downloaded has parameters associated with it, so once run can read them on the host computer.

I have looked into `'ClickOnce'` with the `xml manifest (similar to Java WebStart)` but I am concerned about lack of native functionality in Chrome and Firefox (this is a must). I have also looked into storing it in the executable filename, but the `255 character limit` concerns me.

I was wondering if there was any way to pass parameters to an executable that is downloaded from a website, where I am hosting the website?

Comment: Does it have to be executable right away or would it also be possible to make a ZIP file, have the user unzip it and then run the exe? In that case you could package a normal XML configuration file filled with the respective parameters so that instead of a single self-contained EXE you have an EXE and its .exe.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of.

Most executables that does something like this, tucks on some data at the end of the executable before it is downloaded. As such the executable reads its own file and finds the data at the end.

Adobe Creative Cloud uses this for instance. If you pick an application to install on the website, a small stub executable is downloaded, figures out if it has to install Creative Cloud shell application, and then launches it with information about which program to install.

Comment: Thank you Lasse. Are you able to expand on this please? What sort of data at the end of the executable would be used? Are you speaking in terms of the filename, or the actual source code being edited?

Comment: The executable is just a sequence of bytes, you can append more bytes there. You need to decide on a format for these so that you can identify how many bytes you have appended, a typical way would be to first just append whatever bytes you want to store extra, and then append a 2 or 4-byte integer value containing that number of bytes. For instance, if you append 2 KiB of extra data you would first do that, and then append a 2-byte integer containing the value 2048 (2 KiB). You would then first read this length and then read those bytes, when the program executes.